# Some Widgets in the Right Side Bar and the whole Footer section is not working in a Wordpress Site

Tags: plugins, widgets, footer

My [WordPress Website](https://digitalgoutam.com/) is not working properly. Some Widgets in the Right Side Bar and the whole Footer section is not working. I contacted Theme Support (Generatepress) first. They checked it and told me to discuss with Jetpack support as there was no issue with Theme. Jetpack Wordpress Support told me to go through some steps like deactivating theme to the default one or by deactivating plugins.

If Jetpack or the Theme had issues, then why my [another site](https://motivehuman.com) is working properly?  Is there any issue with coding? I am having the problem for the last 25 days. Can you help me out?

Comment: As it stands, your question isn't a good fit for a Q&A site like this one. Please [edit it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/368862/edit) to provide context: what *specific* problem are you having? What steps have you taken to try to resolve it? Also, if you're having widget problems, it's probable that you'll need to reach out to the support team for the theme that you're using.

Comment: edited as per your contexts